# Foreach loop for binding key/value ObservableArray

Tags: knockout.js

I'm trying to create a menu based on an observablearray filled with menu items. I also have div's which should get visible when the menu item is clicked, the problem is that these div's had visible bindings based on the array position of their specified menu item. This worked till i tried to remove/add some menu item to the array and i realised it is a horrible way of binding the menu items to the divs.

As a solution I decided to use a key/value observablearray so it wouldn't matter if a menu item was added or removed. I got this to work for single menu items with bindings but I can't get it to work with a foreach loop (to show a set of menu items).

Here is the Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Dennis50/uu2u90my/

For example I would get this to work:

```
<h2 data-bind="text: $root.parentArray()[0].project.childObservableArray()[0].klimaat.destUrl()"></h2>
```

But when I try to get it to work for multiple menu items I can't get this to work:

```
<div data-bind="foreach: $root.parentArray()[0].project.childObservableArray()[0]">
   <h2 data-bind="text: destUrl()"></h2>    
</div>
```

So how do I bind these menuitems using the foreach loop and is it even the best solution to this problem?

Comment: You could use `Object.keys(...)` like in this updated [sample](http://jsfiddle.net/uu2u90my/9/). I'd suggest you a better approach, but I can't understand what are you trying to achieve.

Comment: Thanks, that solved my problem! I'd like to hear your better approach though, this example is part of a much larger menu in which the user also gets to add/remove new menu items and clicking on a menu item shows a certain div in which the user can fill in data.

Comment: Ok, @raheelshan suggested a good solution. How does it differ from what you're trying to achieve and what should be done differently?

Comment: I think having to push every menu item is gonna be a pain because the bigger menu is 4 or 5 levels deep and has quite some menu items, so its easier for someone else to edit the array rather than having to figure out the structure of the whole menu. I'll mark his answer as correct for somebody having a similar problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can follow this simple and nice solution

View

```
<ul data-bind='foreach:Menu'>
    <li data-bind="text:Description,click:Action"></li>
</ul>   

<div data-bind="visible:FirstDiv">
    Hi !i am first div
</div>

<div data-bind="visible:SecondDiv">
    And i am the second one
</div>
```

Viewmodel

```
function Menu(obj){
    var self = this
    self.Description = ko.observable(obj.Description)
    self.Action = obj.Action
}
var vm = function(){
    var self = this
    self.Menu = ko.observableArray([])
    self.FirstDiv = ko.observable(true)
    self.SecondDiv = ko.observable(false)

    self.LoadData = function(){
        self.Menu.push(new Menu({ Description: 'Home', Action : self.EnableFirstDiv }))
        self.Menu.push(new Menu({ Description: 'About', Action : self.EnableSecondDiv }))
    }

    self.EnableFirstDiv = function (data) {
        self.SecondDiv(false)
        self.FirstDiv(true)
    }

    self.EnableSecondDiv = function (data) {
        self.FirstDiv(false)
        self.SecondDiv(true)
    }        

    self.LoadData();
}    
$('document').ready(function () {
    ko.applyBindings(new vm())
})
```

### Fiddle Demo