# Mvc and konckout: click data bind won't redirect to another action

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, knockout.js

I want to have in foreach loop list of a href labels with links to MyAction.

In Edit.cshtml `(http://localhost/mysite/Order/Edit/4)` in foreach loop (knockout) I have a href for each item:

```
<a href="#" data-bind="click: $parent.EditForStore">Eddit</a>
```

Method is implemented in ViewModel.js:

```
self.EditForStore  = function (item) {
        console.log(item.IdStore());
        var idStore = item.IdStore();

        //var urlMeta = '@Url.Action("MyAction", "MyController", new { pStoreId = ' + idStore.toString() + ' })';

        var urlMeta = '@Url.Action("MyAction", "MyController", new { pStoreId = 4 })';

        //var myURL = '@Url.Action("MyAction", "MyController")';
        window.location.href = urlMeta;
    };
```

I cannot redirect to MyAction.
When I set location.href , it redirect to http address:

```
http://localhost/mysite/Order/Edit/4/MyAction/MyController?pStoreId=4
```

I cannot change the location.href, I only appends text to my current address.

Comment: Can you log out what is inside the `urlMeta` before setting the window.location?

Comment: In urlMeta is http://localhost/mysite/MyAction/MyController?pStoreId=4 and when I set location.href it redirect me to http://localhost/mysite/Order/Edit/4/http://localhost/mysite/MyController/MyAction?pStoreId=4

Comment: Which browser are you using? Do you get the same behaviour if you try it in different browsers?

Comment: Firefox, I will test on another browser

Comment: @Url.Action is Razor syntax and needs to be in the cshtml file

Comment: Take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25607057/foreach-loop-for-binding-key-value-observablearray/25608253#25608253) example might be helpful

Comment: On the chrome I have the same result, if @Url.Action is wrong how it should look to be right ?

Comment: <input type="button" value="Create" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("MyAction", "MyController", new { pStoreId =  "  IdStore()  "  })    '" /> How to here inject knockout value ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A technique I have used for getting server side routes into knockout is to generate the route with a known parameter value and store it as a data attribute.  Then knockout then pushes the data value into the href.

You can take advantage of the $element context variable to supply the current element into a function declared on the parent viewModel in a `foreach` binding, the use the `attr` binding to update the href attribute.

For example...

---

**HTML**

```
<div data-bind="foreach: stores">
    <a href="#" data-url='@Url.Action("MyAction", "MyController", new { pStoreId = 0 }' data-bind="attr: { 'href' :  $parent.buildUrl($element, id) }, text: id"></a>
</div>
```

---

**Javascript**

```
var ViewModel = (function() {
    var ctor = function ViewModel() {
        this.stores = ko.observableArray( [{ id: 1 }, {id:2}, {id:3}, {id:4} ]);
    };

    ctor.prototype.buildUrl = function(element, data) {
        return element.getAttribute('data-url').replace('pStoreId=0', 'pStoreId=' + data);
    };
    return ctor;
})();

ko.applyBindings( new ViewModel() );
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/9Lz4493d/ for a sample (without the razor syntax and a hard coded data-url attribute, but you get the idea.)

The Url builder function could easily be enhanced to supply the parameter name, etc.